# Uploading mulitple images in react using redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-toolkit

I have a function that uploads multiple images and sends to the server:

```js
    const handleFileChange = (e) => {
       const images = e.target.files;
       const formData = new FormData();
       formData.append('image', images);
   
       if (images) {
         dispatch(uploadProductImage(formData));
       }
     };
```

But when this is dispatched the payload being sent is image: `[object FileList]` so by default this is empty and the response sent by the server is an empty array. Perhaps there's something I'm missing?

My uploadProductImage() looks like:

```js
  export const uploadProductImage = createAsyncThunk('products/uploadProductImage',
    async (formData, thunkAPI) => {
    return uploadProductImageThunk('/uploadImage', formData, thunkAPI);
    });
```

I tried spreading out the images but that wasn't even needed. I also tried passing in the images directly but it's not working. I used this same setup to upload single image and I know it should probably be a bit different but I can't find any article that helps yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer. Since it is an object that had nested objects what I did was iterate over the object and then append each item to the formData.

```js
  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const images = e.target.files;
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let image of images) {
      formData.append('image', image);
    }

    if (images) {
      dispatch(uploadProductImage(formData));
    }
  };
```

Thanks to @abolfazl for helping me look in that direction.